# Using same table in subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am failing to convert next SQL code into laravel eloquent:

```
SELECT t1.template, t1.created_at
FROM sent_emails t1
where created_at = (
    select max(created_at) from sent_emails t2 where t2.template = t1.template
)
group by t1.created_at, t1.template
```

or:

```
SELECT t1.template, t1.created_at
FROM sent_emails t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT Max(created_at) date, template
    FROM   sent_emails 
    GROUP BY template 
) AS t2 
    ON t1.template = t2.template
    AND t1.created_at = t2.date
group by t1.created_at, t1.template
```

Both queries return same data set. Creating subquery in separate variable is not an option as I need multiple values to be returned from it.

I also don't know how can I set alias name if I create table using models (and not using `DB::`), so this is my unsuccessful try:

```
$sent_emails = SentEmail::where('created_at', function($query) {
            SentEmail::where('template', 't1.template')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        })->groupBy('template', 'created_at')->get(['template', 'created_at']);
```

Comment: Please post your so far attempted Query Builder expression.

Comment: in the where closer, you need to do something like $query->where(subquery results here)

Answer (score 0):

You query should be something like this (I'm not at a computer to test this, so it may require further editing)

```
$sent_emails = SentEmail::where('created_at', function($query) {
            $query->where('created_at', SentEmail::->whereColumn('column_name', 'table.column_name')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->max('created_at'));
        })->groupBy('template', 'created_at')->get(['template', 'created_at']);
```

Comment: Does `table.column_name` refer to table outside this function (should I give an alias to that table and then use it here)?

Comment: @niksrb i was following an example from https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements for table aliasing in a where function